# How can a down-vote count exceed a viewed count for a particular question?

Tags: discussion, bug, asking-questions, stack-overflow-app

Recently I posted a question. I received some basic comments but no answer.

Later I found answer on my own and so posted it. As soon as I posted answer of my own question, I got 6 downvotes in a row within 10 seconds. I was amazed. Then I saw view count and found that it was only viewed by 5 people.

How can a question which was viewed only 5 times can get 6 down-votes?

Later when I came back I found that all the down-votes were removed and basic comments of a conversation between me and a particular user were also deleted.

I got message saying `User was removed` all the 6 times.

See below-

[image]

**My conclusion:**

- There is a bug in stackoverflow because down-votes count can't exceed
  a viewed count for any question. This condition is not feasible.
- There is some service/process in stackoverflow that gives alerts to
  the Administrator when someone does a series of down-votes or
  upvotes.
- Administrator removed 6 different users from stackoverflow.
- When any user is removed from stackoverflow then its down-vote (or
  upvote) to any of our post is also automatically deleted.
- Chosen Comments on my question were manually deleted by the
  Administrator.

Comment: probably because view count is cached, while downvote count is more up to date

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: The question I linked above is the same incident, and there's discussion about the minor view count difference there. It's almost always due to caching, if I remember correctly. As you can see in the answer there, this was manually brought to our attention by multiple folks and the culprit dealt with.

Comment: @BradLarson:  That indicates what caused the initial downvotes, but not the discrepancy in the view.

Comment: Disclosing this kind of info is not exactly beneficial.  But given the large number of accounts and the very short delay between votes it is somewhat likely that a bot was used.

Comment: view count is cached. Downvote count is also cached? who deleted user ?  A user was deleted or users?

Comment: @MyGod Vote count is not cached, but the view count is not very important so it doesn't matter how often it updates really.

Comment: @MyGod The information of who violated SE rules should be kept secret and not publicly discussed.

Comment: Correct SE terminology: we have Moderators (on each site), Community Managers and Developers. No "administrator".

Comment: @BradLarson- Just to bring to your kind notice that the question that you linked above was created by the same user who saw this abnormal behavior in my own question posted on the same day.